# Ссылки с помощью SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Как убрать линии, которые находятся под текстом?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходный код:

```
val spanTxt = SpannableStringBuilder(
                "Нажимая на кнопку «Зарегистрироваться» Вы соглашаетесь с Условиями сервиса")
    spanTxt.append(" Условиями сервиса")
    spanTxt.setSpan(object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(widget: View) {
            presenter.navigateToPolicy()
        }
    }, spanTxt.length - "Условиями сервиса".length, spanTxt.length, 0)
    spanTxt.append(" и")
    spanTxt.append(" Политикой конфиденциальности")
    spanTxt.setSpan(object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(widget: View) {
            presenter.navigateToPolicy()
        }
    }, spanTxt.length - " Политикой конфиденциальности".length, spanTxt.length, 0)

    regPolicyDescription.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    regPolicyDescription.text = spanTxt
```

Comment: Посмотрите варианты здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007147/how-to-get-rid-of-the-underline-in-a-spannable-string-with-a-clickable-object

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, он помог мне

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как оказалось, можно просто переопределить метод `updateDrawState` и указать для переменной `isUnderlineText` значение `false`

```
spanTxt.setSpan(object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(widget: View) {
            presenter.navigateToPolicy()
        }

        override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint?) {
            ds?.isUnderlineText = false
        }
    }
```